# Dynamically select part of object properties

Tags: c#, .net, class, asp.net-core, reflection

Is there a method to select a part of object properties dynamically ?

I'm on .net Core 3, in a web api project

I need to send to the client a subSet of source properties based on their value

Example 1:

```
    source = { max="",min="1", label="Code"};
    sendToClient obj should be 
    output = { min="1",label="Code"}
```

Example 2:

```
    source = { max="35",min="1", label="MixerColor",width="",height="",rounded=null};
    sendToClient should be 
    output = { max="35",min="1",label="Code"}
```

if source[prop] Not (null or empty) => send source[prop] to client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do this by converting object to json and back

```
var source = new { max = "", min = "1", label = "Code" };
            var tmp=JObject.FromObject(source);
            tmp.Property("max").Remove();
           var newSource= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(tmp.ToString());
```